# Take a photo with Camera but don't save it as a file, only show it

Tags: java, android, camera, imageview

In my Android project I want to take a photo with Camera **but don't save it as a file, only show it on a ImageView**, as a drawable or other.

In my project I can see the camera, like the code below.

I tryied a lot of ways, but I cant take the photo without save it SDCard.

### ShowCamera.java

```java
 public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder holdMe;
    private Camera theCamera;

    public ShowCamera(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        theCamera = camera;
        holdMe = getHolder();
        holdMe.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            theCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            theCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

       private Camera cameraObject;
       private ShowCamera showCamera;

       public static Camera isCameraAvailiable(){
          Camera object = null;
          try {
             object = Camera.open(); 
          }
          catch (Exception e){
          }
          return object; 
       }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);

          cameraObject = isCameraAvailiable();
          showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);
          final FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
          preview.addView(showCamera);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not forget to put this in your AndroidManifest.xml: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

So, you can follow this example: http://hmkcode.com/android-camera-taking-photos-camera/

Comment: Yes, thanks.
I can save the photo with the properly code, but I don't want to do it. I only want to show a "preview" or a "freeze" of the camera in a ImageView, always without save any data in the storage.

Comment: You want to show the photo in a ImageView, but you don't want to save it, all right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include this line inside ur button click routine:

> mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

And then create a routine:

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback(){ //+ a lot of things...}
```

The code below should be inside the PictureCallBack routine

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
   File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
      try{
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
         fos.write(data);
         fos.close();
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
      catch(IOException e){}
      File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                      Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
}
```

And try to find the function:

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){}
```

That also should be included!

Answer (score 0):

So you need an image taken from camera and show it on a `ImageView`, **not to save it?**

Create a picture callback to receive data from camera and decode it to Bitmap:

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera c) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
};
```

Call camera capture (when capture button clicked):

```
try {
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // take picture failed
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```